# WebView2 can't print html document with embedded pdf data (base64)

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, webview2

In my WPF application I have a window that loads an html string to show to the user. Then there is a Button that let the user open the printing dialog and print the document (using the javascript code window.print();).

The problem is: if the html document contains an embedded pdf (<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0...) then the command does nothing: I don't get any error, but the dialog never opens.

Funny thing: if I press Ctrl + P the dialog shows up regularly.

Note: I don't need to print the pdf document, but I need to print the document that contains it (the html document)

- Is there any way to fix this?
- Is this a known bug in the WebView2 control?
- Is there any way to see what is happening and why the dialog does not appear?
- Is there any way to "send" the Ctrl + P command to the control and get the same result?

Here it is the same code in a sample application to reproduce the problem (comment the call to GetHtmlWithEmbeddedPdf to see the dialog working, and decomment it to see the error).

The Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WebViewApp.WebWindowWithPrint"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WebViewApp" xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WebWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="Button_Click">Print</Button>
    <wpf:WebView2 Name="WpfBrowser" />
</DockPanel>
```

The code behind (the embedded pdf contains a simple red title and a simple text):

```
public partial class WebWindowWithPrint : Window
{
    public WebWindowWithPrint()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnContentRendered(e);

        var webView2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync();
        await WpfBrowser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webView2Environment);

        var html = @"<html><head><title>Test title</title></head><body><p>Test</p></body></html>";
        html = GetHtmlWithEmbeddedPdf();  // comment this to see the printing dialog
        WpfBrowser.NavigateToString(html);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WpfBrowser.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.print();");
    }

    private string GetHtmlWithEmbeddedPdf()
    {
        return @"<html><head></head>
        <body>
        <p>Html document with an embedded base64 pdf</p>
           <div><object data=""data:application/pdf;base64,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"" type=""application/pdf"" width=""100%"" height=""500px""></object>
           </div></body></html>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a security feature, not a bug. It's also not limited to WebView2 but applies to Chromium in general.

The embedded PDF object is causing the HTML document to be [sandboxed](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/origin.html#sandboxing). Thus preventing `window.print()` from executing as usual.

This is as specified by the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#printing):

> The printing steps for a Document document are:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. If the active sandboxing flag set of document has the sandboxed modals flag set, then return.

This is also why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> still works and brings up the print dialog, as it is a user action not affected by this security issue.

### **Workaround**

Until WebView2 "natively" supports printing, the best workaround I can currently think of is to load the PDF inside an `iframe`, thus freeing the parent document from being sandboxed:

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0..."
```

Comment: It works! In my case I am getting the full html string from a storage, but I can replace the object tag with iframe and the document is not sandboxed anymore. Thanks